# respond.js set up tutorial

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I cannot find info anywhere on exactly how to setup respond.js.

I unzipped into htdocs - is this correct? Or do I just need respond.min.js in htdocs?

Then simply reference the file like this...

```
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
```

Currently, I have this in my head section, have tried before and after my media queries, yet NO stylesheet is used.

Is there a tutorial anyhwere on exactly how to set up resonse.js, as I have no idea if I am doing something wrong or whether there is another problem.

Any help would be much appreciated, my site is FINALLY finished yet I don;t want it to go live without media queries and currently if I use media queries, no stylseheet is loaded at all in IE8.

Thanks

This is my current code;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="http://localhost/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen and (min-device-width:600px) and (max-device-width:1024px)" href="http://localhost/oldScreen.css">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen and (min-device-width:1025px)" href="http://localhost/home.css">


                <title>Eastbourne Netball League[Home] </title>
    </head>
```

Comment: if `response.min.js` is in the same folder as your html file, it should be fine. When you unzipped it, maybe it created a subfolder. In that case it should be `<script src="subfoldername/response.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Well it come sin a folder with loads of subfolders and files, but ther eis no explanation as to what to do with these files. Everything is in htdocs, I have tried leaving response.min.js in its folder/sub folder and referencing it fully, and have tried just pasting it on its own into htdocs, and referencing as above. Nothing happens

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", does it mean it can't find the file? Or it just means that your media queries don't work?

Comment: well the media queries work without response.js in chrome, IE9 etc, but just by having them, it means when I run in IE8, NO stylesheet is run, it is just plain html. Hence, by using response.js, I should be able to use my existing media queries and even get IE8 to choose a file depending on screen size. However, I have no idea what the problem is, but the problem remains exactly the same as before I found respond.js - media queries work in chrome, IE9, FF, but NO stylesheet is used in IE8. This is the worst case scenario!

Comment: In the Developer Tool panel (on any recent browser), do you see a `404` error? (or any javascript error in the console)

Comment: no, and it appears in firebug as if it is working. I have the html5 shim script too, which works, and have tried the respond.js script tags in there, also with no luck

Comment: any other ideas, really at my wits end here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, since the file is loaded, the problem has to come from one of these 2 points:

From the documentation:

> - Craft your CSS with min/max-width media queries to adapt your layout **from mobile (first)** all the way up to desktop
>     @media screen and (min-width: 480px){
>         ...styles for 480px and up go here
>     }
> - Reference the respond.min.js script (1kb min/gzipped) **after all of your CSS** (the earlier it runs, the greater chance IE users will not see a flash of un-media'd content)

My guess is the second point :)

I hope it helps.

**[edit]**

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width:1024px)" href="http://localhost/oldScreen.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen and (min-width:1025px)" href="http://localhost/home.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <title>Eastbourne Netball League[Home] </title>
</head>
```

If this doesn't work, put it this way inside your CSS file:

```
@media {min-width:600px) and (max-width:1024px) {

    /* your css here */

}

@media {min-width:1025px) {

    /* your css here */

}
```

Therefore, you can even put all your CSS in the same file

Comment: Ok so I have posted my current code above. Note that I have tried the code with the script src for respond.js after the CSS media queries, with no luck. I have also tried it not inside the <!--[if lt IE 9]>, both before and after the CSS styesheet calls and still no CSS file is called in IE8.

Comment: Try my solution, if it doesn't work, that means respond.js doesn't support the `media` property. You will have to put the media queries inside your CSS file like I just added in my answer.

Comment: Or maybe they don't support `min-device-width`, did you try `min-width` instead?

Comment: thank you for all the help, but one more question - how do I reference the CSS files, ie how will it know which one to pick if I am not including the min/max width in the HTML?

Comment: It would read both files, but only apply the style in the right `@media` query. But like I said, you can even put it all in the same css file.

Comment: wow. OK. That last one did it! I cannot thank you enough for your persistence. Out of interest, as I have no way of testing on a different screen tonight - how does the min-width/max-width compare to min/max-device width?

Comment: @user2933231 You're welcome, don't forget to mark the question as answered. `min-width` is the window width, `min-device-width` is the resolution. On mobile devices, it's the same since you can't resize the window (except change the orientation), so it only applies to resizable browsers.

Comment: ok, be interesting to see how my stylesheet for smaller screens now works! Thanks again